# Do react components continue to remain impure even if we place side effects inside event handlers/use effect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Side effects make a function impure, and one of the examples of side effects is

> [calling other functions with side effects.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20an%20operation,the%20invoker%20of%20the%20operation.)

React documentation states that side effects [usually belong inside event handlers or useEffect.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-can-cause-side-effects) However, by using functions with impure code such as event handlers with side effects, or useEffect that's handling a side effect, doesn't that make the component impure?

Answer (score 1):

The same page you cited it state that:

> React assumes that every component you write is a pure function. This means that React components you write must always **return** the same **JSX** given the same inputs,

and

> In React, side effects usually belong inside event handlers. Event handlers are functions that React runs when you perform some action—for example, when you click a button. Even though event handlers are defined inside your component, they don’t run during rendering! So event handlers don’t need to be pure.

In other words a component only needs to be pure in the rendering phase (creating the JSX code) not after (or before, `useLayoutEffect`) the rendering. The `useEffect` and *handlers* run after. For example  in the case of `useEffect` (with an empty dependency array) just runs after of initial rendering  and if some var has changed during the exucution of `useEffect` then the component is re rendered again.

I have to add that React always recommend try to avoid the use of useEffect refactoring the code or in the case of fetching data it is better to use native tools provided by frameworks.